# Buid two associations between two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have a strange requirement in my project. Actually, I have two tables (users,galleries). I would like to access galleries table with has_one as well as has_many associations. The main purpose is to get the profile snap of the user by using has_one relation and to get the personally uploaded pictures by using has_many relation.

Initially I go with polymorphic association to resolve this (FYI, please find the below code snippet) .But I think it is not the right approach for this problem.

Would anybody explain how to handle this case in an efficient way.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :galaries, as: :imageable
  has_one :galary, as: :imageable
end

class Galary < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a column `user_id` in `galaries` table in order to link the the user to the galary (profile snap).

```
rails generate migration add_user_id_to_galaries user_id:string
```

This will generate the migration:

```
class AddUserIdToGalaries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :galaries, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`

---

Moving to our Models now:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :galaries, as: :imageable
  has_one :galary #profile snap
end

class Galary < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user #profile snap user
end
```

Comment: You mean, I need to maintain polymorphic and has_one combination. Are there any alternatives by using class_name etc ?

Comment: since the user has_many :galaries already, then the class name will not identify it

Comment: Absolutely, then is there any alternative like by placing class_name at has_many etc

Comment: Check tihom's answer. Its going to work, but its is not as efficient  as this. as his suggestion will add more condition to the query. `User.first.galary` will result in a query searching in 3 columns instead of 1.

Comment: @pramod if these did't answer your questions, please post your alternative answer.

Comment: Sure, i will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with scoped `has_one` association. Although not necessary, you can define which `gallery` is selected in the `has_one` using a scope. If no scope is given, the `has_one` would return the first match.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :gallaries
  has_one :gallery, -> { where primary: true }
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  #user_id, primary (boolean variable to select the gallery in has one association)
  attr_accessible :name
  belongs_to :user
end
```